# How to create a mysql database on localmachine and remote connect to it

Tags: mysql

How can I create a mysql database on my own pc and remote connect to it from external source?

What do I need?

Comment: To do research. Google is a great place to start. So are the MySQL docs.

Comment: You're going to need an understanding of networking, firewalls, possibly NAT or router configuration, dynamic DNS depending on your local setup. There's quite a lot to it.  Also MySQL user/host based GRANTs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and use XAMPP

Find it here: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

It will let you host Mysql server inlcuding PHPMyAdmin. If you open your ports, you can connect remotely to PHPMyAdmin and manage your Mysql database.

Comment: It's the "open your ports" part that the OP is going to have issues with. There's so much more to it than you have glossed over here. And I don't think the OP wants to remotely manage via a web application, but connect directly to the database from an external source.